# Наследование и иерархия в Entity Framework с дополнительными полями в наследниках

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Допустим есть такие dto

```
abstract class ObjectShapeDto
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}

class CircleShapeDto : ObjectShapeDto 
{ 
   public int Radius {get;set;}
}

class QuadroShapeDto : ObjectShapeDto 
{ 
   public int Width {get;set;}
}
```

Я бы хотел чтобы в БД это хранилось в одной и таблице Shapes, и был Descriminator с названием типа:

```
Id   X  Y    Descriminator
__________________________
1    0  0    Triangle
2    0  0    Circle
3    5  7    Quadro
```

Но вот остальные поля с доп инфой о каждом классе
(**Radius** у класса **CircleShapeDto**  и **Width** у класс **QuadroShapeDto**)
как хранить их в отдельных таблицах?

То есть были бы таблицы например CircleInfo, QuadroInfo

Answer (score 0):

Это подход Table Per Type. Пример здесь [Подход TPT - Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.2.php).
Более подробно про типы наследования можно прочитать здесь [Inheritance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Сравнение производительности двух подходов Table per Type и Table per Hierarchy в EF Core: [Inheritance mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/modeling-for-performance#inheritance-mapping). TPH выигрывает.

Comment: это решит проблему только хранения разных типов. а как сделать универсальный вариант для хранения еще доп информации в разных таблицах по каждому типу?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. В примере с метанита есть таблица Phone, в которой хранятся общие поля для всех таблиц, по аналогии с ObjectShapeDto из вашего примера. И наследуемые от нее классы, для которых создаются отдельные таблицы только с дополнительными полями. То есть в C# мы используем классы-наследники, а в БД у нас отдельные таблицы с доп. полями. И при запросе EF джойнит наши таблички, возвращая поля как для базового класса, так и для класса-наследника.

Comment: А, понял, не хватает discriminator. А в каком сценарии он нужен? EF самостоятельно обрабатывает наследование типов.

Comment: У меня на данный момент сделано с использованием discriminator, переделывать не вариант. На данный момент 23 наследника имеется. Но добавлять в основную таблицу поля нужные для каждого наследника не оптимально будет, это будет таблица с кучей полей тогда. А хотелось бы доп инфу разнести в разные таблицы. Чтобы я вытянул все shapes, а доп поля для где они есть в наследниках сами подтянулись

Comment: Предложенный вариант сработает и с наличием поля discriminator, если оно уже есть и используется. Будет один базовый класс и 23 класса-наследника, для каждого класса будет создана отдельная табличка с дополнительными полями. Свойство Discriminator можно автоматически заполнять в конструкторе каждого наследуемого типа.